# My discord bot is continuously sending messages after a command, discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

In my Discord bot I've created a set of commands which I want only people with a specific role are able to use. So when I send the command in Discord the expected message comes but the same message is continuously being sent by the bot infinitely. The only way to stop it is to turn of the bot. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: I have added the image of the code

Answer (score 1):

The bot is replying to itself, that's why it's creating an infinity loop. In the message event, you could prevent that by using the `.bot` key, for example:

Discord V12:

```js
client.on("message", message => {
    if(message.author.bot === true) return;
    // Enter the rest of your code below.

});
```

Discord V13:

```js
client.on("messageCreate", message => {
    if(message.author.bot === true) return;
    // Enter the rest of your code below.

});
```

Answer (score 0):

What may be happening is that your bot is responding to itself. The fix is pretty simple - just add

```js
if (msg.author.bot) return
```

at the top of your message listener.